# Keras: Embedding in LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm, embedding

In a keras example on LSTM for modeling IMDB sequence data (https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py), there is an embedding layer before input into a LSTM layer:

```
model.add(Embedding(max_features,128)) #max_features=20000
model.add(LSTM(128))
```

What does the embedding layer really do? In this case, does that mean the length of the input sequence into the LSTM layer is 128? If so, can I write the LSTM layer as:

```
model.add(LSTM(128,input_shape=(128,1))
```

But it is also noted the input `X_train` has subjected to `pad_sequences` processing:

```
print('Pad sequences (samples x time)')
X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=maxlen) #maxlen=80
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=maxlen) #maxlen=80
```

It seems the input sequence length is 80?

Answer (score 4):

[To quote the documentation](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/#embedding):

> Turns positive integers (indexes) into dense vectors of fixed size.
>   eg. [[4], [20]] -> [[0.25, 0.1], [0.6, -0.2]]

Basically this transforms indexes (that represent which words your IMDB review contained) to a vector with the given size (in your case 128).

If you don't know what embeddings are in general, [here is the wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding):

> Word embedding is the collective name for a set of language modeling
>   and feature learning techniques in natural language processing (NLP)
>   where words or phrases from the vocabulary are mapped to vectors of
>   real numbers in a low-dimensional space relative to the vocabulary
>   size ("continuous space").

Coming back to the other question you've asked:

> In this case, does that means the length of the input sequence into
>   the LSTM layer is 128?

not quite. For recurrent nets you'll have a time dimension and a feature dimension. 128 is your feature dimension, as in how many dimensions each embedding vector should have. The time dimension in your example is what is stored in `maxlen`, which is used to generate the training sequences.

Whatever you supply as 128 to the [LSTM layer is the actual number of output units of the LSTM](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm).