# Using LSTM layer without Embedding

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

I have been trying to train a model for tf.keras.datasets.imdb using LSTM in tensorflow.
After some processing i have input -> x_train shape: (25000, 100).
Since i cannot feed it in a LSTM layer directly, i used a lambda function to change dimension of input:

```
model = Sequential([
Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x,axis=-1)),
LSTM(62, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True),
LSTM(32),
Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

But i am getting a horrible accuracy (around 55%).

But upon using embedding layer the accuracy increases to 90% using same hyper parameters:

```
model = Sequential([
Embedding(5000, 32),
LSTM(62, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True),
LSTM(32),
Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])﻿
```

Am i doing something wrong in the first case?

Comment: here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759194/keras-embedding-in-lstm